# ploting the recombination rate in a forward bias depletion

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction

I'm trying to figure out how to plot the graph in b. 
I know I need to go according to the recombination formula in a, and Ei is linear, but for some reason something won't work.[image]

is there anyone who can help me out with this?

by the way, I have solved a, but it would help to see if I got it right.

Thanks!

about part b : I think the fuction looks something like f(x) I worte here, and after plugging in the values the ends of the depletion I've gotten the this plot.
does anyone know if I'm on the right path here?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering SE. To get help with homework questions here you need to show what you have already tried. If you want us to comment on your proof of part a you need to show us your solution (legibly please). To get help with part b please show what you have tried so far and hopefully someone more familiar with the subject than me willl be along to suggest where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks! I added it to the question.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help with this one ?

Comment: You could also ask on the Physics SE forum where people may be more familiar with solid-state physics.